# Spring 3 RequestMapping - match the rest of the path with option of specific reserved end paths

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-restcontroller

Title might be confusing but essentially what I'm trying to do is explained below.

If I had a url /app/{var1}/foo for a given class controller

And now at this point I'd like to be able to have a single method that matches:

```
/bar/bar1/bar2 (where bar1 and bar2 are both optional i.e. it could be bar, bar/bar1 or bar/bar1/bar2)
```

I do also want a second method that could handle

```
/bar/X, /bar/bar1/X, bar/bar1/bar2/X (all to be captured and handled by the same method).
```

Any ideas how the regex here would go. I have the documentation for how to capture the rest of the URL i.e  foo/**. But in my case I guess i'm looking to capture cases where the url may also end in a specific way without certainty of the depth.

Comment: you cannot map `/bar/bar1/bar2` and `/bar/bar1/X` to different methods **unless** there is a restriction on how those url parts are formed. i.e X only consists of numbers.

Comment: Well with the assumption that bar2 can be anything other than the pattern in X - So this part I think I is easy. The question is how we get the hierarchy of the url to point to the same method. i.e. bar/..../X